# Getting rid of hard coded values when dealing with lookup tables and related business logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, business-logic

Example case:

We're building a renting service, using SQL Server. Information about items that can be rented is stored in a table. Each item has a state that can be either "Available", "Rented" or "Broken". The different states reside in a lookup table.

ItemState table:

id  name
1   'Available'
2   'Rented'
3   'Broken'

Adding to this we have a business rule which states that whenever an item is returned, it's state is changed from "Rented" to "Available".
This could be done with a an update statement like "update Items set state=1 where id=@itemid". In application code we might have an enum that maps to the ItemState id:s. However, these contain hard coded values that could lead to maintenance issues later on. Say if a developer were to change the set of states but forgot to fix the related business logic layer...

What good methods or alternate designs are there for dealing with this type of design issues?
Links to related articles are also appreciated in addition to direct answers.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience this is a case where you actually *have* to hardcode, preferably by using an Enum which integer values match the id's of your lookup tables. I can't see nothing wrong with saying that "1" is always "Available" and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

Most systems that I've seen hard code the lookup table values and live with it. That's because, in practice, code tables rarely change as much as you think they might. And if they ever do change, you generally need to re-compile any programs that rely on that DDL anyway.

That said, if you want to make the code maintainable (a laudable goal), the best approach would be to externalize the values into a properties file. Then you can edit this file later without having to re-code your entire app.

The limiting factor here is that your app depends for its own internal state on the value you get from the lookup table, so that implies a certain amount of coupling.

For lookups where the app *doesn't* rely on that code, (for instance, if your code table stores a list of two-letter state codes for use in an address drop-down), then you can lazily load the codes into an object and access them only when needed. But that won't work for what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

When you have your lookup tables as well as enums defined in the code, then you always have an issue with keeping them in sync. There is not much that can be done here. Both live effectively in two different worlds and are generally unaware of each other.

You may wish to reject using lookup tables and only let your business logic operate these values. In that case you miss the options of relying on referential integrity to back you ap on the data integrity.

The other option is to build up your application in that way that you never need these values in your code. That means moving part of your business logic to the database layer, meaning, putting them in stored procedures and triggers. This will also have the benefit of being agnostic to the client. Anyone can invoke SPs and get assured the data will be kept in the consistence state, consistent with your business logic rules as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have some predefined value that never changes, be it an integer, a string or something else.

In your case, the numerical value of the state is the state's surrogate `PRIMARY KEY` which should never change in a well-designed database.

If you're concerned about the consistency, use a `CHAR` code: `A`, `R` or `B`.

However, you should stick to it as well as to a numerical code so that `A` always means `Available` etc.

You database structure should be documented as well as the code is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends entirely on the language you're using: solutions for this are not the same in Java, PHP, Smalltalk or even Assembler...

But let me tell you something: while it's true hard coded values are not a great thing, there are times in which you do need them. And this one is pretty much one of them: **you need to declare in your code your current knowledge of the business logic, which includes these hard coded states**.

So, in this particular case, I would hard code those values.

Answer (score 1):

Don't overdesign it. Before trying to come up with a solution to this problem, you need to figure out if it's even a problem. Can you think of any legit hypothetical scenario where you would change the values in the itemState table? Not just "What if someone changes this table?" but "Someone wants to change this table in X way for Y reason, what effect would that have?". You need to stay realistic.

New state? you add a row, but it doesn't affect the existing ones.
Removing a state? You have to remove the references to it in code anyway.
Changing the id of a state? There is no legit reason to do that.
Changing the name of a state? There is no legit reason to do that.

So there really should be no reason to worry about this. But if you must have this cleanly maintainable in the case of irrational people who randomly decide to change Available to 2 because it just fits their Feng Shui better, make sure all tables are generated via a script which reads these values from a configuration file, and then make sure all code reads constants from that same configuration file. Then you have one definition location and any time you want to change the value you modify that configuration file instead of the DB/code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common problem and a valid concern, that's why I googled and found this article in the first place.

What about creating a public static class to hold all the lookup values, but instead of hard-coding, we initialize these values when the application is loaded and use names to refer them?

In my application, we tried this, it worked. Also you can do some checking, e.g. the number of different possible values of a lookup in code should be the same as in db, if it's not, log/email/etc. But I don't want to manually code this for the status of 40+ biz entities.

Moreover, this can be part of the bigger problem of OR mapping. We're exposed with too much details of the persistence layer, and thus we have to take care of it. With technologies like Entity Framework, we don't need to worry about the "sync" part because it's automated, am I right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've used a similar method to what you're describing - a table in the database with values and descriptions (useful for reporting, etc.) and an enum in code.  I've handled the synchronization with a comment in code saying something like "these values are taken from table X in database ABC" so that the programmer knows the database needs to be updated.  To prevent changes from the database side without the corresponding changes in code I set permissions on the table so that only certain people (who hopefully remember they need to change the code as well) have access.

Answer (score 0):

The values have to be hard-coded, which effectively means that they can't be changed in the database, which means that storing them in the database is redundant.

Therefore, hard-code them and don't have a lookup table in the database. Instead store the items state directly in the items table.

Comment: You're recommending storing values such as `'Available'` as a `VARCHAR`?  This adds to storage requirements, and creates a risk that when an attribute is changed, it's not changed everywhere, leading to inconsistent data.  Having a text value will tempt people into making up new values for special circumstances; keeping a table of allowed values discourages this.  Finally, having a separate table allows one to add attributes to these statuses, such as a CanBeRented flag - handy as the number of possible values increases.

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your database so that your application doesn't actually have to care about the codes themselves, but rather the business rules behind them.

I have done both of the following:

1. Do one or more of your codes have a certain characteristic, such as `IsAvailable`, that the application cares about? If so, add it as a flag column to the code table, where those that match are set to `true` (or your DB's equivalent), and those that don't are set to `false`.
2. Do you need to use a specific, single code under a certain condition? You can create a singleton table, named something like `EnvironmentSettings`, with a column such as `ItemStateIdOnReturn` that's a foreign key to the `ItemState` table.

If I wanted to avoid declaring an enum in the application, I would use #2 to address the example in the question.

Whether you take this approach depends on your application's priorities. This type of structure comes at the cost of additional development and lookup overhead. Plus, if every individual code comes with its own business rules, then it's not practical to create one new column per required code.

But, it may be worthwhile if you don't want to worry about synchronizing your application with the contents of a code table.